# MongoDB Aggregate: Find amount of intersecting date ranges with each month

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

### Problem

I want to do a task using only MongoDB aggregate, without additional code. This has to do with the environment we are running the aggregate.

We have a `users` collection. In our app, users can be created and deleted. The `createdAt` field has the date when the user was created, and the `deletedAt` field has the date the user was deleted.

I want to create an aggregate that is able to calculate the amount of active (not deleted) different users we had per month, starting from the month the first user was created, up to now.

In more nerdy words, I want to find the amount of date ranges, each date range starting from `createdAt` and ending at `deletedAt`, that intersect with each month, starting from the month the first user was created. We want to avoid inputting each month manually, since it would ruin the automation we want to make, so we need to get the months programmatically, so the aggregation will work now and in the future.

### Example

Let's assume my collection `users` has these three entries:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2996846471279461asd87"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-07-26T04:05:36.314Z"),
    "deletedAt" : ISODate("2023-11-15T07:06:36.314Z"),
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("6fbf2996846471279461asd87"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-09-05T09:05:36.314Z"),
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("7fbf2996846471279461asd87"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-10-14T04:05:36.314Z"),
    "deletedAt" : ISODate("2023-10-15T07:06:36.314Z"),
},
```

So I'd expect the output to be something like that:

```
{
  "month": "2023-07",
  "count": 1,
}, {
  "month": "2023-08",
  "count": 1,
}, {
  "month": "2023-09",
  "count": 2,
}, {
  "month": "2023-10",
  "count": 3,
}, {
  "month": "2023-11",
  "count": 2,
}, {
  "month": "2023-12",
  "count": 1,
}, {
  "month": "2024-01",
  "count": 1,
},
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your current work so we can start from where you are blocked? There is a lot of requirements now.

Comment: Hey @ray I'm sorry for not adding that. Actually, I'm so lost on this problem that I couldn't even get halfway there, so I don't really have anything to show. I know the problem is complex, but I couldn't find a way to split it into smaller problems to put here. Honestly, I'm having some hard time with aggregate haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the date operators with `$range` to create a list of months dates for each document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      months: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            startMonth: {$dateTrunc: {date: "$createdAt", unit: "month"}},
            endMonth: {$dateTrunc: {date: {$ifNull: ["$deletedAt", "$$NOW"]}, unit: "month"}}
          },
          in: {$map: {
              input: {$range: [
                  0,
                  {$add: [
                      {$dateDiff: {startDate: "$$startMonth", endDate: "$$endMonth", unit: "month"}},
                      1
                  ]}
              ]},
              in: {$dateToString: {
                  date: {$dateAdd: {
                      startDate: "$$startMonth", unit: "month", amount: "$$this"
                  }},
                  format: "%Y-%m"
              }}
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }},
  {$unwind: "$months"},
  {$group: {_id: "$months", count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$sort: {_id: 1}},
  {$project: {createdAt: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K2vEkqUDyr1)